# anaconda launches the wrong python and spyder version

Tags: python-3.x, spyder, anaconda3

I installed anaconda on ubuntu 18 (not for the first time) and created a new environment (using the navigator) with python 3.7 (in addition to the 3.8 in the base environment). I installed spyder in the new environment, but when launching it using the navigator, I get the spyder of the base environment (with python 3.8). The only way I found around this is to activate the new environment from the terminal and type "spyder" which launches the correct version. Any ideas why the navigator directs to the wrong spyder version?

Comment: Are you activating the environment inside the navigator before launching spyder?

Comment: Yes, I go to that environment, I even see that it is the correct spyder version, but when I launch it, I get the version associated with the base environment. This is not my first installation of anaconda in Ubuntu and it did not happen before.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily maintain separate environments for Python 3.7 programs and Python 3.8 programs on the same com:

```
conda create --name py3 python=3.7
```

or

```
conda create -n py37 python=3.7
```

Activate and use the Python 3 environment.in Linux:

```
conda activate py37
```

Comment: I did that too. It worked fine and created the new environment in the navigator. However, when I try to launch spyder from the navigator, it launches spyder of the base environment even if I am at my new environment. I don't understand this.

Comment: read this ( https://docs.spyder-ide.org/current/installation.html)

Comment: Thanks for the link but I still don't see why launching spyder from the navigator always directs to the spyder version associated with the base environment, even if I do it from a different environment.  It is as if there is something wrong with my navigator, since launching from the terminal works fine.