# Anaconda shows spyder 4.2.5, but launches 5.0.3

Tags: python, pip, anaconda, version, spyder

Latest Ubuntu here.

I installed anaconda. No errors. Anaconda-navigator shows Spyder 4.2.5 installed. Since it would not update it (shows progress bar but nothing happens), I manually updated spyder using
`conda update spyder` (everything under the same, default environment).

Now I can launch spyder from command line, and it opens Spyder 5.0.3. Beautiful.
However anaconda-navigator still shows Spyder 4.2.5 as the one installed. And offers to upgrade it (which never worked) only to 5.0.0

Also, if I remove Spyder from anaconda-navigator, it actually removes the 5.0.3 version (which won't launch even from command line afterwards), thus it is actually linked to the 5.0.3 version and the 4.2.5 seems to be not installed at all.

Is Anaconda looking somewhere else to show that older version (which is not what launches when I press the "launch" button)?

Note 1: I did have a previous pip-vs-anaconda hell, so that might be part (or all) of the problem. I may have messed up some files
Note 2: I did check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64854407/anaconda-launches-the-wrong-python-and-spyder-version), but it doesn't really got an answer